# How to count in a join statement

Tags: mysql

I have got table `post`: `int post_id, varchar title, text content`
And table `comment`:`int comment_id, int post_id, varchar content` where post_id is a foreign key references table post.

How do i get the post_id and sum of comments of each post order by comments count. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want posts that have no comments:

```
SELECT
    post.post_id,
    --post.title,
    --post.content,
    COUNT(comment.post_id) AS comment_count
FROM post
LEFT JOIN comment ON post.post_id = comment.post_id
GROUP BY post.post_id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```

(This query uses the MySQLs [GROUP BY with hidden columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) extension).

If you don't want posts that have no comments you can use a simpler query:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS comment_count
FROM comment
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```

Comment: @Mark Byers I tried my own and it worked. My sql is:select p.post_id,
        count(comm.comment_id)as comment_count
        from comment as comm, post as p
        where comm.post_id=p.post_id
GROUP BY p.post_id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC. Which one is better to use?

Comment: @LotusH: Your query won't return posts that have no comments.

Comment: That's enough for my application :) Thanks for your help.