# How do you get the comment count of the post through mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I would like to get numbers of comments for each posts using mysql.

I have two tables, one is post table and the other is comment table. Post table has `id`, `title` and `content` field while comment has `id`, `post_id`, `author` and `comment` field.

The result that would like to achieve is like

```
---------------------------------------------
Title               Comment Count
---------------------------------------------
My fancy post             2
---------------------------------------------
```

Let me know if you have confusion about my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.title,
    COUNT(b.post_id) AS 'Comment Count'
FROM
    post a
LEFT JOIN
    comment b ON a.id = b.post_id
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

This will account for posts that don't have any comments.

Comment: I also found the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595824/how-to-count-in-a-join-statement?rq=1